# Python selenium and gui

Tags: python, user-interface, selenium

First of all, my knowledge of programming is equal to zero, approximately :)

I want to scrap data with pages like this:

[image]

And I did it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.rezultati.com/utakmica/4G3g57cl/#detalji")

liga = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fleft")
for post in liga:
    print(post.text.split(' ', 1)[0])

datum = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mstat-date")
for post in datum:
   print(post.text.split(' ', 1)[0])

imena = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tname")
for post in imena:
    print(post.text)

kosevi = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("score")
for post in kosevi:
    print(post.text)
```

And now I want to change link, so I made this:

[image]

```
import sys from tkinter import *

def Get():
    link = ment.get()
    return

root = Tk()
ment = StringVar()

root.title("Program")
root.geometry("700x100")

theTekst = Label(root, text="link:")
theTekst.pack()

e = Entry(root, width = 110, textvariable = ment)
e.pack()

dugme = Button(root, text="Start", command = Get)
dugme.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

and it works

But do not know how to unite these two codes..
Do you have any suggestions or could you point me in the direction of some useful resources?